# working with EXECUTE sp_executesql with paramter in Pivot query in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query regarding how to give parameter in pivot when you run the script using EXECUTE sp_executesql.

```
DECLARE @FactorText AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @RequestID AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

   SELECT @FactorText = COALESCE(@FactorText + '], ', '') + CAST('[' + FactorText AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
   FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT FactorText 
         FROM QuoteHODFCreditDebit 
         where RequestId = @RequestID AND AppliedValue!=0.00
    ) AS QuoteHODFCreditDebit

    SET  @FactorText =  @FactorText + ']'

    DECLARE @DynamicPIVOT AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ParmDefinition AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @DynamicPIVOT = 'SELECT @FactorText
             FROM 
            (
                SELECT case
                   when(appliedValue < 0) then quotename(convert(nvarchar(100), ABS(AppliedValue)),''('')
                     else CONVERT(nvarchar(100),AppliedValue)
                  end as AppliedValue,  FactorText FROM
                     QuoteHODFCreditDebit where RequestId = @ResRequest
                     and appliedValue!=0.00
            ) CreditDebitFactor
            PIVOT (
                MAX(AppliedValue) FOR FactorText IN (@FactorText)
            ) Result;'

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@ResRequest NVARCHAR(MAX),@FactorText NVARCHAR(MAX)';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicPIVOT, @ParmDefinition, @ResRequest = @RequestID, @FactorText = @FactorText;
```

In the above query, @ResRequest parameter did not raise any error, but as a parameter @FactorText raised the error.

> Error : Incorrect syntax near '@FactorText'.

Please solve out this query .

If you have a sample example for my requirement, then you can post.

Thanks in advance to all SQL magician .

Comment: Why all that DBMS tags?

Comment: You need to be careful not to tag every DBMS. This is obviously sql server. The reason for the error is because @FactorText is out of scope for your dynamic sql.

Comment: You can't use a variable in an IN clause or select list

Comment: Try to differentiate in two `@FactorText`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a variable in an in clause or select list.  If you could you would not need the dynamic SQL at all.

If you had the current version of SQL Server you would be able to do this with a function call instead of dynamic SQL.

Here is how you do it with dynamic SQL:

```
   SELECT @DynamicPIVOT = 'SELECT '+@FactorText+'
             FROM 
            (
                SELECT case
                   when(appliedValue < 0) then quotename(convert(nvarchar(100), ABS(AppliedValue)),''('')
                     else CONVERT(nvarchar(100),AppliedValue)
                  end as AppliedValue,  FactorText FROM
                     QuoteHODFCreditDebit where RequestId = @ResRequest
                     and appliedValue!=0.00
            ) CreditDebitFactor
            PIVOT (
                MAX(AppliedValue) FOR FactorText IN ('+@FactorText+')
            ) Result;'

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@ResRequest NVARCHAR(MAX)';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicPIVOT, @ParmDefinition, @ResRequest = @RequestID;
```